# Can anyone tell me why this high composite number finder dosen't work?

Tags: python-3.x

What is wrong with the following?

```
divisor = 1 
divisors_d = 0
divisors_max = 0 
divisors = []
divisors_number = []
start = int(input("Number:")) 

for n in range(1,start+1): 

if n % divisor == 0:
    divisors.append(divisor)
    divisor=divisor+1
    divisors_d=divisors_d+1
    if divisors_max<divisors_d:
        c = n
        divisors_number = divisors
        del(divisors[:])
        divisors_max = divisors_d 
        divisors_d = 0

elif n%divisor != 0:
    divisor = divisor + 1

print("The number is: " + str(c))
print("Number of divisors is " + str(divisors_max))
print("The divisors are :" + str(divisors_number))
```

I have tried to solve this for a while and i can't make it work can someone tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link please. Please tell us what it is supposed to do, what it actually ends up doing, and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your indentations weren't good and the algorithm has some problems and isn't really efficient. A good approach would be:

```
number=int(input("Enter a number: ")) 
num=0 
maxnum=0
maxx=0
div=[]
maxdiv=[]
for i in range(1,number+1):
    for x in range(1,i+1):
        if i % x == 0:
            num+=1
            div.append(x)
    if num>maxnum:
        maxnum=num
        maxx=i
        maxdiv=div
    num=0
    div=[]

print("The number is "+str(maxx))
print("Its divisor count is "+str(len(maxdiv)))
print("Its divisors are "+str(maxdiv))
```

### Explanation:

```
number = the limit number 
num = used for counting divisors
maxnum = the maximum number of divisors
```

The highest number of divisors can always be accessed with `len(maxdiv)`

Notice that instead of creating another variable to store the maximum divisor count of a number, I used `len(maxdiv)`, to clean up the code a bit.

Hope it helps!